# How to upload file and save it with original name in storage folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want save uploaded file with original name.What i must add to this code?

Below's my code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $originalname = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename =$originalname;
        $file->move('public/', $filename);
    }
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#storing-uploaded-files

Comment: how to use it? it give me error everytime i try it

Comment: Checked the folder permissions? What error would that be? Can you please edit your question and paste the error there?

Comment: "The file "C:\xampp\tmp\phpD2B2.tmp" does not exist" when i add  $path = $request->image->store($originalname);

Comment: `$path = $request->photo->store('images');` ... "_The store method accepts the path where the file should be stored relative to the filesystem's configured root directory._" Is `$originalname` a path? Sounds more like a complete filename. "_If you do not want a file name to be automatically generated, you may use the storeAs method, which accepts the path, file name, and disk name as its arguments_"

Comment: it give me error "Driver [] is not supported." when i add   $path = $request->image->storeAs('public',$filename,'local');

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use the `storeAs` method, which receives the path, the file name, and the (optional) disk as its arguments:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $originalname = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = $file->storeAs('public/', $originalname);
    }
}
```

Comment: Error "Call to a member function hashName() on string"

Answer (score 1):

Upload files with original fileName.

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $file_path = $request->file('image')->storeAs('dir_name', request()->file('image')->getClientOriginalName(), 'optional_disk_name');
}

// pass the disk name as the third argument to the storeAs method: ex. local,s3,etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($request->hasFile('image'))
{
    $file = $request->file('image');
    $originalname = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $img = Image::make($file->getRealPath());
    $img->stream();
    Storage::disk('local')->put('images/'.$originalname, $img, 'public');
}
```

Comment: Error "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Image' not found"

Comment: Please add `use Image;` on top of your controller

Comment: In your app.php Add this in your aliases:  "'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,"
and in your providers "Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,"
Don't forget to do php artisan config:cache after this.